# SSAS Connection in Excel not possible through HTTPS

Tags: excel, https, ssas

today I have set up a web access for my SSAS database, which is running on a remote server in the same domain as my PC. I did the initial configuration with HTTP and everything worked smoothly, SSMS and Excel could both access the SSAS database through the link.

I then proceeded to configure a HTTPS access. I already had a certificate ready so the setup was fairly simple. I then checked my firewall settings on the remote server to ensure 443 is unblocked.
I tried to connect to the new url **https://servername.de/OLAP/msmdpump.dll** in SSMS, and it still worked just fine, so both the URL and the Firewall were set up properly. I could also reach the URL using Edge. It didn't actually show anything because of permissions, but it could reach it.

Then I went to try it in Excel using "From Analysis Services" in Get Data, and when I try to connect to the URL mentioned above it says that it can either not connect to the URL, or that there is no Analysis Services running. But since I can reach the database using SSMS, both of those seem to be ruled out.

Another weird thing is that when I select "From SQL Server Analysis Services Database (Import)" in Excel, the connection works as intended and it starts importing data from the SSAS cube.

I assume I am using the wrong syntax to connect using "From Analysis Services" since everything else is set up correctly. Does anyone perhaps know how to fix this?